# Why do objective-c array parameters not use colon notation?

Tags: objective-c

Im currently learning some objective-c from the big ranch guide book. My understanding is that methods with multiple parameters use colons to separate each parameter, but when reading about creating arrays, i found this snippet of code:

```
 NSArray *dateList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:now, tomorrow, yesterday, nil];
```

This has left me confused as i thought objective-c method parameters must each be preceded by a portion of the method name along with a colon. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Completely separate from the answers below: there's a more modern syntax for this, being only `@[now, tomorrow, yesterday]`. Provided none of `now`, `tomorrow` or `yesterday` is `nil` then that'll be functionally identical to the `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an exception to the rule; this is commonly called a [variadic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). If you look at the definition in NSArray.h:

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

you see that you can specify an arbitrary number of parameters, as long as the last one is `nil` (this is called the [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)).

This saves the developers from creating a large number of different methods having roughly the same functionality, each of which accept a different number of parameters. They did so in `NSObject`, where you have

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1;
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)object1 withObject:(id)object2;
```

(but no further methods).

Comment: you are very fast, and i am very jealous.

Comment: Damn these elves spoiling the fun for everyone! :–)

Comment: And worth adding by way of explanation that this is a carryover from C, which allows this sort of arbitrary-argument-length function calling behavior, created primarily for things like `printf` and subject to some syntactic restrictions and somewhat of a hassle to unpack on the callee side. Modern ObjC could certainly exist without such syntax (instead using array literals) but you'll see it from time to time.

Answer (score 4):

The method only has one parameter, a variable parameter list.

Here is the Objective-C declaration from the Apple Developer website:

```
+ (instancetype nonnull)arrayWithObjects:(ObjectType nonnull)firstObj, ...;
```

There's no need for colon separation, because the object list is treated as one parameter, even thought it looks like many parameters!